# React SPA idle session timeout implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, single-page-application

I have read the article regarding this matter at [link](https://medium.com/@daveford/session-timeout-in-spas-3ce3dc6d9427), however I am having trouble implementing the third step

> When the 31 minutes is up, I make a call to the server to see if our session is still alive. If no, I set a client-side variable called isLoggedIn to false. If yes, I set isLoggedIn to true and reset the timer.

Im new to React, and im just wondering how to implement this, I dont want to manually modify all the .tsx files to call the session checker, what im thinking is if there is a common/global listener in react that triggers everytime I navigate screens or everytime I call the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an npm package named react-idle-timer. You would just need to make some changes to the App.tsx file. Rest all could remain same.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer